# Always keep the cursor centered in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to keep my cursor centered at any time.

I manage, thanks to a high valued `scrolloff` as mentioned on [this Vim Tips page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen), to keep it centered when there is line around the cursor but I can't make Vim behave that way when my cursor is near the first or last lines. Is it possible to make Vim adds the "tilde" `~` lines to replace "real lines"?

Comment: Vim cannot show the "~ tilda lines" at the top, only at the bottom. Might be a nice enhancement to consider.

Answer (score 19):

You can try this mapping:

```
:nnoremap j jzz
:nnoremap k kzz
```

And if you often use `G` to jump to end of a file, you probably also want

```
:nnoremap G Gzz
```

Comment: Near :/ It works only when the cursor is at the last line but not for the first line. However, it is precisely the behavior I was looking for :)

Comment: @kev Nice. Never knew about `zz`.  [Have an upvote](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/302/170/685.png)!

Comment: This is great, but I often edit files with long lines with word wrap off. Is there a similar solution that keeps the cursor centred _horizontally_ as well?

Comment: @baitisj maybe try `:nnoremap l lzszH`

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what made kev but if (like me) you're a silly full keyboard user, you can add

```
:nnoremap j jzz
:nnoremap k kzz
:nnoremap <Down> jzz
:nnoremap <Up> kzz
```

Thanks to @kev

Answer (score 2):

The mappings suggested by [kev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398805/8096230) work for basic navigation in normal mode, but not more complicated movements such as searching. Nor will they do anything for you in insert mode, which is where I personally spend most of my time: at the bottom of the file writing!

A simple if heavy handed solution I have is

```
:autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call CentreCursor()
```

with the user-defined function

```
function! CentreCursor()
    let pos = getpos(".")
    normal! zz
    call setpos(".", pos)
endfunction
```

which saves the current cursor position, centres the view and then restores the cursor position (I originally tried the `autocmd` with just `* zz`, but this seemed to break appending to the end of a line).

As the name implies, [CursorMoved(I)](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved) triggers whenever the cursor moves in Normal or Visual (Insert) mode, so this should cover all bases. It is obviously triggered very often, so using it as a hook is possibly not a good idea. I haven't noticed a performance hit yet; your mileage may vary (ideally there would be a `LineMoved` event or similar, but there isn't).

The above gives what, coming to vim, I expected `:set scrolloff=999` to do. It will not do anything at the top of the file, since there are no `~` lines there. If you were insistent on having the cursor centred, even when opening a new file, a (very) crude workaround would be to insert a few blank lines on `BufRead`. You will probably also want to remove then on `BufLeave` or similar. I haven't done any vimscript before now but can get your started on this if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess about your motivation, but in case you want a single, uncluttered window with editing front and center, I can recommend the [vimroom plugin](http://projects.mikewest.org/vimroom/). While it doesn't nail down the cursor in the middle, it uses `'scrolloff'` and empty padding windows on all sides to avoid that the cursor drifts too much to the editor borders.