# Keep cursor line vertically centered in vim

Tags: vim

I want the cursor to be constantly in the middle of my screen in vim.
I am not very comfortable looking constantly down to the end of the file.
What commands in the config will you advise to solve the problem?

Comment: There're ways to keep cursor in the middle of the window, but I don't get the relation between this and the title.

Comment: I wish my eyes would never go down to the screen. If you connect scrollof, then at the end of the page cursor it still goes down. I would like to add some hidden blank lines at the end of each file somehow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides `:set so=999`, I also tried these 2 commands to map the normal <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>j</kbd> to "scroll up/down one line and place that line at the center of the window":

```
:nnoremap k kzz
:nnoremap j jzz
```

A little different from setting `so`, when moving cursor down to the end of the file, it still remains at the center. However it doesn't affect the behavior of <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

Comment: I have vim 8.2 and 8.1. Not able to try it on previous versions.

Comment: This is genius!

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with Jensun. This is a great idea.

Remapping the `k` and `j` key. Inside of the ~/.vimrc using `:nnoremap`.

Remapping it to:
`k - up, zz - center line, k = kzz`
`j - down, zz - center screen, j = jzz`

Answer (score 8):

```
:set scrolloff=999
```

If you set `scrollof` to a very large value (999) the cursor line will always be
in the middle of the window (except at the start or end of the file or
when long lines wrap).

Comment: it helped me, but when I reach the end of the page, the cursor still goes down.

Comment: of course it does, how would you be able to edit the last line of your file, otherwise?

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen

Comment: @toydarian The answer to that is simply the reverse of what vim does when viewing a file whose linecount doesn't match the screen height: if you make a 5 line file, row 6 and beyond will all be filled with `~` (tilde) characters, signifying that that is dead space--not part of the file.

Therefore, when one reaches the end of the page, one could (optimistically) hope the current line is still in the center, while it starts to fill up (to half way) with tilde characters.

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint, if a user felt most capable in vim with the current line always being in the _middle of the monitor_, I'd argue it would even be a useful tweak to put the first line half way down the screen, with the top 50% filled with tildes, as well.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63326139/12222900), this is how to extend this functionality to searching and insert mode. It saves the current cursor position, centers the view, and then restores the cursor position.

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call Center_cursor()

function! Center_cursor()
    let pos = getpos(".")
    normal! zz
    call setpos(".", pos)
endfunction
```